# How to access NTFS Format File System in android?

Tags: android, usb, ntfs

We have a USB port in our android tablet(version 4.0.3 - IceCreamSandwich).

I am using Windows 7 and Eclipse to develop my android applications.

I want to access NTFS File System Format through android tablet. I want to perform the File Operations are Create, Read, Update and Delete. I know the Linux kernel does not support NTFS File System Format.

I need to learn and I am also eager to know. The NTFS File Systems to access the File Operations in android tablet.

I know it is possible. But i don't know how to access the NTFS File systems to access File Operations through programmatically.

Please Help and Guide for me. I need sample code.

Thanks
Regards
Bala

Comment: @droidhot My android tablet contains Default File Manager. I am deleting some files and then read some File content using Default File Manager. How is it possible in the Default File manager? Adobe Reader can read the NTFS Format Files. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set up a Windows share over your Wifi network. Problem solved :)

Comment: he is asking about accesing NTFS file s/m in android device (a pen drive connected 2 tablet for eg)